# nquad gives wrong answers

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to calculate a joint probability, the mean and deviation are fixed, the user gives the parameters and the sign, < or > and also the correlation of the two variables, the results of the integral are every time almost zero (10^-5 and lower).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import nquad

def function(x, mean, deviation):
    ratio = abs((np.log(x) - np.log(mean)) / (np.sqrt(2) * deviation))
    return ratio


def Joint(x1, mean1, deviation1, sign1, x2, mean2, deviation2, sign2, correlation):

    f1 = lambda x: ((np.log(x) - np.log(mean1)) / deviation1) ** 2
    f2 = lambda x, y: 2 * correlation * ((np.log(x) - np.log(mean1)
                                             ) / deviation1) * ((np.log(y) - np.log(mean2)) / deviation2)

    f3 = lambda y: ((np.log(y) - np.log(mean2)) / deviation2) ** 2

    p = lambda x, y: np.exp((-0.5 / (1 - correlation ** 2)) * (f1(x) - f2(x, y) + f3(y))
                               )/(2 * np.pi * x * y * deviation1 * deviation2 * np.sqrt(1 - correlation ** 2))
    if sign1 == "1" and sign2 == "1":
        result, error = spi.nquad(p, [[10**(-4), prob.function(x2, mean2, deviation2)], [10**(-4), prob.function(x1, mean1, deviation1)
                                                                                         ]])
    elif sign1 == "2" and sign2 == "1":
        result, error = spi.nquad(p, [[10**(-4), prob.function(x2, mean2, deviation2)], [
                                  prob.function(x1, mean1, deviation1), 10**8]])
    elif sign1 == "1" and sign2 == "2":
        result, error = spi.nquad(p, [[prob.function(x2, mean2, deviation2), 10**8], [10**(-4), prob.function(x1, mean1, deviation1)
                                                                                      ]])
    elif sign1 == "2" and sign2 == "2":
        result, error = nquad(p, [[prob.function(
            x2, mean2, deviation2), 10**8], [prob.function(x1, mean1, deviation1), 10**8]])
    return result
```

I have tried to set options on `nquad` but it doesn't work. The exact same formulas on Matlab are giving the right results.

UPDATE: I figured out that i was calculating the value of the function instead of the function, in the integral.Now i am trying to calculate the function and get this : TypeError: must be real number, not function,

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: show the actual error

Comment: for x1 =6, mean1=1.4, deviation1=1.25,sign1=2,21,mean2=39.9 ,deviation2=0.85 ,sign2=1 ,correlation=0.6 i get as result :The joint probability is P( Qstroke,C ≥ 6.0 , Sₘ, kA/μs < 21.0 )= 2.0010321527111768e-41 but the real result is 0.22%